# Error raise while deploying yolov5 custom model

Tags: python, pip, yolov5

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming_Basic\AI_Basic\yolov5_AIBasic\yolov5\yo.py", line 4, in <module>
    model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path = '/yolov5/best.pt', force_reload=True)  # or yolov5m, yolov5l, yolov5x, custom
  File "C:\Users\Jayaram\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 399, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jayaram\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 428, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jayaram/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 70, in custom
    return _create(path, autoshape=autoshape, verbose=verbose, device=device)
  File "C:\Users\Jayaram/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 65, in _create
    raise Exception(s) from e
Exception: path is on mount 'C:', start on mount 'D:'. Cache may be out of date, try `force_reload=True` or see https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/36 for help.
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail. Also did you try to run the command with `force_reload=True`?

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title. Format error message (Stackoveflow has special methods to format code in question). And show code which makes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error while using the yolov5 flask API.

The possible reason for this error is the `os.relpath` does not give you a relative path between two directories. On Windows, a relative path doesn't even exist if the two directories are on different drives (which is exactly what the error message says).

This response, [here](https://bugs.python.org/msg94780), helps to understand the problem better.

One of the ways to avoid this problem is to copy your app to `C:` drive, select your python interpreter and try to execute the code again. Windows has no absolute root directory - instead, it has a root
directory for each drive. That means that `D:` is a path relative to
the current drive rather than an absolute path.

You can see the c: and d: drive conflict in the top few lines of your error codes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\Programming_Basic\AI_Basic\yolov5_AIBasic\yolov5\yo.py", line 4, 
in <module> model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path = 
'/yolov5/best.pt', force_reload=True)  # or yolov5m, yolov5l, yolov5x, 
custom

File "C:\Users\Jayaram\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
packages\torch\hub.py", line 399, in load
model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
```

The best way to avoid it is to paste the code in C drive or you need to make your path absolute instead of relative.